# The IP Address api is not working when a access through a VPN proxy . How can i access it?

Tags: reactjs

I have integrated ipaddress api in react js .The https://api64.ipify.org api is not working when a access through a VPN proxy . How can i access it ? ?

I want to make api working with VPN proxy also

Comment: "api is not working when a access through a VPN proxy" - isn't that the point?

Comment: Yes. I. can any api to find ip Address of device on client side with VPN prxoy also